# Use elasticsearch on Wagtail frontend?

Tags: elasticsearch, frontend, wagtail

is there a way to use the elasticsearch module that is incorporated in Wagatail admin also on the frontend? If yes, do you have any examples/ideas how would that be possible? Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/topics/search/searching.html#an-example-page-search-view

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a front-end framework like React, you can use Wagtail's backend utilities to index models/pages and query the Elasticsearch server directly with [Searchkit](http://www.searchkit.co/). At my organization we firewall our Elasticsearch server and built a proxy as a simple Django `view`.

Otherwise, you can query ES in a `view` and use the standard template tags within Wagtail.